# How to print a continues page in crystal report with c#?

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have developed a POS application in C# with crystal report, i want the invoice to be printed on a continues paper(thermal printer size), i have designed a receipt, but when it prints, it goes on multiple pages. i have even tried to collapse header and footer of report. but no good.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you print screen your current output, draw your expected output and show the code?

Comment: i dont have the template of reciept i want, the problem is, i want to print the reciept without page break, but crystal report puts a line break, thats not good for a invoice to be printed. i just want to print the invoice constantly, and the code is i simply fill my data table with the products, and the pass this datatable to my report, and prints it to the default printer

Comment: No one can understand. Maybe you need to read "How to ask questions on StackOverflow" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also if you don't help readers to know what you want and make it easy for them, then they won't help you in return. If you want a good answer, ask a good question.

Comment: great mate.. i have asked a real simple question in simple words.. thanks anyways

Comment: Well, look here is a simple question too: "_How can I fix my refrigerator?_" However, no one can answer that still. So it is not about simplicity. Read my first comment and do it, if you want better responses. Again, readers need to know what you are talking about and by just setting tags it won't help much.

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf i think Usman Farooq asked a very simple question. He designed a report (Point of Sale invoice report) and as every one knows that point of sale invoice is printed on thermal printer and length of invoice depends on the number of items purchased by customer.  Usman's and my problem is that we want to print a long invoice when there are lots of items purchased. But Crystal Reports is cutting thermal paper at A4 Length. How to avoid this cut or page break?